# NestJS & Multer image type check error response to client

Tags: nestjs, multer

I have successfully used Multer with NestJs to check for fileTypes so only images are saved. However when a non image is uploaded the fileCheck works great but Nest returns a 500 error to the client. I want it to return an error message to the client.

Other answers on SO show how to do this using Node but I want to know how to do it using Nest. I followed a video tutorial to get this far but now need this extra functionality.

Controller.ts

```
@Controller("photos")
export class PhotosController {
    @Post("upload")
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("photo", { 
        storage: diskStorage({
            destination: './uploads',
            filename: editFileName
        }),
        fileFilter: imageFileFilter
    }))
    async uploadSingle(@UploadedFile() file) {
        console.log(file);
        const response = {
            originalname: file.originalname,
            filename: file.filename,
        };
        return response;
    }
```

file-upload.utils.ts

```
export const imageFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
      return callback(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    callback(null, true);
  };

  export const editFileName = (req, file, callback) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split('.')[0];
    const fileExtName = extname(file.originalname);
    const randomName = Array(4)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
      .join('');
    callback(null, `${name}-${randomName}${fileExtName}`);
  };
```

How can I catch the error in ImageFileFilter if it exists then still return a response to the client?